# Remove right click context menu from column headers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

In my program I have a datagrid which is bound to an observable list. I want to be able to set the context menu to only display when a row is selected so that there wont be errors with nothing being selected. To do this I would like to be able to disable the context menu on the column headers. Here is the XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgItems" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True">
  <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu>
          <MenuItem Header="Edit Item" Click="EditItem_Click"/>
          <MenuItem Header="Delete Item" Click="DeleteItem_Click"/>
      </ContextMenu>
  </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Caption" Binding="{Binding Caption}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Details" Binding="{Binding Details}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="DateFrom" Binding="{Binding DateFrom}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="DateTo" Binding="{Binding DateTo}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Source" Binding="{Binding Source}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How would I go about disabling the context menus on the headers? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataTrigger` to set the `ContextMenu`. The trigger listens to `SelectedItems.IsEmpty`, if it's `false`, the `ContextMenu` will be set:

```
<DataGrid ... >
   <DataGrid.Resources>
       <ContextMenu x:Key="cm">
            <MenuItem Header="Edit Item" Click="EditItem_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete Item" Click="DeleteItem_Click"/>
       </ContextMenu>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.Style>
      <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
         <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItems.IsEmpty, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false">
                 <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}"/>
             </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.Style>
   <!-- remaining code -->
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: This code gives the error that click events cant be specified on a target tag in a style.

Comment: @K.Burrell see my edit, you need to place the `ContextMenu` as a Resource ***out of the Style's scope***, such as in `DataGrid.Resources`

Answer (score -1):

You can try to intercept the event and mark it as handled.
First add the event on the grid:

```
<DataGrid
ItemsSource="{Binding ClassroomStudents, Mode=TwoWay}"
MouseRightButtonUp="DataGrid_MouseRightButtonUp"
</DataGrid>
```

Then mark it as handled:

```
private void DataGrid_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject depObj = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;

    while(depObj != null && !(depObj is DataGridColumnHeader))
    {
        depObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(depObj);
    }
    if(depObj is DataGridColumnHeader)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please add some explanation to your answer?